# Saving bitmap as a image in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to save a bitmap as a image file. I tried the following code and got error.

```kotlin
val dir = File("/tempfolder/")

if (!dir.exists()) {
    print("dir not exist");
    dir.mkdirs()
}

val output = File("tempfile.jpg")
var os: OutputStream? = null

os = FileOutputStream(output)

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os)

os.flush()
os.close()
```

**Error:**

````
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.io.FileNotFoundException: tempfile.jpg (Read-only file system)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.CanV.touchUp(CanV.kt:190)
        at com.app.symbolrecogniser.CanV.onTouchEvent(CanV.kt:102)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)```
````

Comment: Where do you want to create the directory? You should read into storing file from the [offical guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific)

Comment: mkdird() returns a boolean false/true. You should check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want [`Context#getDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context#getdir) instead

> Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application
> can place its own custom data files. You can use the returned File
> object to create and access files in this directory. Note that files
> created through a File object will only be accessible by your own
> application; you can only set the mode of the entire directory, not of
> individual files.
>
> The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to
> an adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted.
>
> Apps require no extra permissions to read or write to the returned
> path, since this path lives in their private storage.

but there are a few others you can access like `getCacheDir` (for temp stuff, gets wiped when the user clears the app cache or frees up storage), `getFilesDir` (just the main folder that `getDir` creates a new folder in, if you don't actually need a separate folder - gets wiped on app uninstall), and `getExternalFilesDir` (same as `getFilesDir` only it's on external storage, if you want to put things there instead). These are all private storage spaces only your app can access